# Alternative to RecyclerView for older Sdk

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have created an App with RecyclerView but it’s crash in the devices with 4.1 Android OS.
There is an alternative to RecyclerView or i can risolve the problem?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Activity activity;

    private SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences shared;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pref = getPreferences(0);

        Fragment fragment;
        fragment = new DashboardFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_frame, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }//fine OnCreate


}// FINE CLASS
```

Fragment

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.xxx.parser.JSONParser;
import com.xxx.utils.InternetConnection;
import com.xxx.utils.Keys;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class  FragmentCards extends android.app.Fragment {

    View v;
    private RecyclerView myrecyclerview;
    private List<Cards> lstCards;
    //

    private SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences shared;
    String unique_id;

    // Getting application context
    Context context = getActivity();

    //JSON
    private ListView listView;
    RecyclerViewAdapter recyclerAdapter;


    public FragmentCards() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cards_fragment, container, false);
        myrecyclerview = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_rv);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(),lstCards);
        }
        myrecyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        myrecyclerview.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        return v;
//        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //per visualizzare codice
        pref = getActivity().getPreferences(0);
        shared = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("A", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);   // get the sharedpreference set named "A"
        unique_id= shared.getString("unique_id","");
//
//
        lstCards = new ArrayList<>();
//
        goToList();

    } // fine ON CREATE

    public void check_connectivity(){
        View view = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        // Initialize a new Snackbar
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Connessione assente ... riprovo fra 5 secondi", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
        // Change the Snackbar default background color
        View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
        snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
        snackbar.show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                View view = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Connessione in corso ...", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
                // Change the Snackbar default background color
                View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
                snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F9A603"));
                snackbar.show();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        goToList();

                    }
                }, 1500);

            }
        }, 5000);
    }

    public void goToList() {
        if (InternetConnection.checkConnection(getActivity().getApplicationContext())) {

            new GetDataTask().execute();
            View view = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "Connesso", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            // Change the Snackbar default background color
            View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
            snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#258039"));
            snackbar.show();

        } else {
            check_connectivity();

        }
    }

    class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setTitle("Un attimo di pazienza...");
            dialog.setMessage("Carico le tue card");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = JSONParser.getDataById(unique_id);


            try {


                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Keys.KEY_CONTACTS);


                        int lenArray = array.length();
                        if(lenArray > 0) {
                            for(int jIndex = 0; jIndex < lenArray; jIndex++) {


                                JSONObject innerObject = array.getJSONObject(jIndex);
                                String desc_dist = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_DIST);
                                String numero_card = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_NUM_CARD);
                                String totpunti_card = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_TOT_PUNTI);
                                String id_cd = innerObject.getString(Keys.KEY_ID_CD);


                                /**
                                 * Adding name and phone concatenation in List...
                                 */
                                lstCards.add(new Cards( numero_card,desc_dist,totpunti_card,id_cd) );
                            } //fine FOR

                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }
            } catch (JSONException je) {
                Log.i(JSONParser.TAG, "" + je.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return null;
        } // FINE doBackground

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            dialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Checking if List size if more than zero then
             * Update ListView
             */
            if(lstCards.size() > 0) {
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                View view = getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, "No Data Found", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        }
    } // fine GetDataTask
}
```

RecyclerView

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import java.util.List;

    public class RecycleTransCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleTransCardAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


        Context mContext;
        List<InfoCard> mData;
        Dialog myDialog;

        public RecycleTransCardAdapter(Context mContext, List<InfoCard> mData) {
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.mData = mData;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v;
            v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_trans_card, parent, false);
            final MyViewHolder vHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);


            return vHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

// some code
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mData.size();
        }

        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

// some code


            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView) ;
// some code

            }
        }

    }
```

The error is in Fragment at this line:

recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

I have this error only on old OS Android
Example: 4.1 version

Comment: What is crash report? Where is stacktrace? Where is code? Atleast post something.

Comment: Post your stacktrace here so we can help.

Comment: RecyclerView is part of v7 support libs and it  works well with till api level 7. there may be network and thread issue causing  error .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recyclerview is backwards-compatible, assuming you include the support library for RecyclerView v7 in your application's build.gradle file:

```
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0.+"
```

That one will work down as low as Android 2.1 (API level 7)

So you can use recyclerview in device running lower as on Android 2.1 (API level 7), hence the name v7

try adding above library and run app again if still crash happen
update the question with error log of app.

Answer (score 0):

RecyclerView is part of Support Library which you can use it on older devices too. Try to use AndroidX package `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView`
instead of support library.

```
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
```

For more detail about AndroidX explore this address:
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/